# Drupal 7, upload and save image permanently using managed_file

Tags: drupal-7

I can't seem to be able to save image files uploaded using the FAPI.

The images are uploaded as managed files, I need to save them permanently but they are always saved in the database with a status of 1.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks,

//fapi

```
 $form['fieldset_3']['pic_3'] = array(
 '#type' => 'managed_file',
 '#title' => t('Image'),
 '#required' => TRUE,
 '#default_value' => variable_get('pic_3'),    
 '#description' => t('Allowed extensions: gif png jpg jpeg.'),
 '#upload_validators' => array(
 'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
 'file_validate_size' => array('MAX_FILE_SIZE' * 1200 * 300),
 ),  
 '#theme' => 'image_multifield_multitype',
 '#upload_location' => 'public://carousel',
 );
```

//in submit function

```
$file = file_load($form_state['fieldset_1']['pic_1']);
$file = file_save_upload($file->uri,$validators, 'public://carousel/' .  $file->filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
file_save($file);
```

Comment: FWIW, in my case `file_save_upload` failed when I passed it `$file->uri` as above.  I had to use the name of the form element (in the OP's example that would be `'pic_1'`).

Comment: "I need to save them permanently but they are always saved in the database with a status of 1." I don't get it. Isn't 1 the correct status for 'permanent'?

Comment: Yep, that was a typo, I meant 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the problem was the submit handler was not being called...

Answer (score 0):

Load image by the fid and set status to permanent

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['image_fid']);
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file_saved =file_save($file);
variable_set('image_fid', $file_saved->fid);
```